# How to acces SharedPrefences from recyclerView adapter?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-recyclerview

I want to acces SharedPrefences from my adapter because I want to check a variable to set an ImageView visible or gone.

```
class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{


ArrayList<String> mData;
public ImageView mMinus;
public static final String SHARED_PREFS_DATA = "sharedPrefsData";



public MainAdapter(ArrayList<String> data) {
        mData = data;
}



@NonNull
@Override
public MainAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mText.setText(mData.get(position));

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_DATA, 0);
    int a = sharedPreferences.getInt("visible", 0);
    if(a == 0)
       holder.mMinus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else
       holder.mMinus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 

}
```

error: cannot find symbol method getSharedPreferences(String,int)

Comment: Adapter does not have `getSharedPreferences` method. Check which class has this method first.

Comment: it seems like a bad idea to use SharedPreferences inside adapter, why are you doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Pass the `context` from the `Activity` to the `adapter` and using this `context` you can access the `shared preferences`

2.You can also pass the `Activity` reference instead of `Context`

Comment: Another good solution instead of passing a context would be to use ApplicationContext in your adapter, By creating an application class in your project to avoid possible memory leaks actually.